# Editing row data

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
//$id = $_GET['id'];
$GLOBALS['a'] = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
echo "$a";

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'ems');
if (!$db) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$first_name = "";
$last_name = "";
//$mobile = "";
$email  = "";
$gender = "";
$designation_id = "";
$address = "";
$errors = array(); 

if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
  $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['first_name']);
  $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['last_name']);
  //$mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['mobile']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
  $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['gender']);
  $designation_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['designation_id']);
  $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['address']);
  $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  if ($user) { // if user exists

   if ($user['email'] === $email) {
      array_push($errors, "email already exists");
    }
  }

     //  echo "$a";

          $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `first_name` = '$first_name' ,`last_name`='$last_name', `password`='$password',
            `email`='$email', `gender`='$gender', `designation_id`='$designation_id',`address`='$address' WHERE `users`.`id` = '$a'"; 

        if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
            mysqli_close($db);
            header('Location: index.php');
             echo "$a";
            exit;
        } else {
            echo "Error updating  record";
        }
}

?>
```

while trying to update the row through the form it redirects to index page without updating the row....no erros..pls help me.

while trying to update the row through the form it redirects to index page without updating the row....no erros..pls help me.

Comment: its not error, its your message that means `else part execute`. something wrong in your query, print your query and run on sql so its given error or run update record

Comment: You are mixing backticks `\`` & quotes `'`. `'password'` will be treated as string not column name.

Comment: Sougata Bose...updated bro...no errors but row not updated

Answer (score 0):

please try this updated code.May be the issue reason is value not assign properly. So that it's moved else part. Now i have moved the update query inside the POST Check value.

```
<?php
//$id = $_GET['id'];
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'ems');
if (!$db) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$first_name = "";
$last_name = "";
//$mobile = "";
$email  = "";
$gender = "";
$designation_id = "";
$address = "";
$errors = array(); 

if (isset($_POST['reg_user']) && $id!='') {
  $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['first_name']);
  $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['last_name']);
  //$mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['mobile']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
  $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['gender']);
  $designation_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['designation_id']);
  $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['address']);
  $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  if ($user) { // if user exists

   if ($user['email'] === $email) {
      array_push($errors, "email already exists");
    }
  }

  else
  {

          $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `first_name` = '$first_name' ,'last_name'='$last_name', 'password'='$password',
            'email'='$email', 'gender'='$gender', 'designation_id'='$designation_id','address'='$address' WHERE `users`.`id` = '$id'"; 

        if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
            mysqli_close($db);
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit;
        } else {
            echo "Error deleting record";
        }
  } 

}


?>
```

Comment: please add what you update in code and why should try this code?

Comment: where it is `value not assign properly`?

Comment: if $_POST['reg_user'] return empty  OR $_GET['id'] value empty it's not process the update query.

Comment: $id echoing...so no problem with $_GET['id']

Comment: Ok first just print  the sql Query with exit. Then directly run the query to your Phpmyadmin. Check it's return any error message.

EX: echo $sql ;exit;